# How to connect remote Python FTP server to local Python FTP client

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp, ftplib

I am using python FTP server and client program. My need is to run *Python FTP server* on a *remote machine* that is connected on the same network as my local machine. *FTP client* will run from *local machine*, I need to connect FTP server with my FTP client running on local machine.

Please help!

This is my `ftpserver.py`:

```
from pyftpdlib.servers import FTPServer
from pyftpdlib.authorizers import DummyAuthorizer
from pyftpdlib.handlers import FTPHandler

authorizer = DummyAuthorizer()
authorizer.add_user("lokesh", "123", "current_dir", perm="elradfmw")
authorizer.add_anonymous("curent_dir", perm="elradfmw")

handler = FTPHandler
handler.authorizer = authorizer

server=FTPServer(("localhost",8080),handler)
server.serve_forever()
```

This is my `ftpclient.py` that needs to connect with the above server:

```
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP('')
host='localhost'
port=8080
ftp.connect(host,port)
ftp.login()

print(ftp.getwelcome())
print('Current Directory ',ftp.pwd())

ftp.dir()

ftp.quit()
```

When I test my server and client on same machine it worked. But when I run the same server on another machine and tried to connect with my client it gave me error:

> error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run the client on another machine, you have to connect to the host of the server, not to "localhost":

```
host='<server_host>'
```

Run `ipconfig` on your Windows server machine and look for "IPv4 address".

Answer (score 0):

Replace `port = 1027` with `port = 8080` in your ftpclient file.